# PostSharp: BindingException when using with Microsoft.Bcl in Windows Phone 7 project

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, postsharp

Following code throws exception during compilation:

```cs
[PSerializable]
public class MyAspectAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect {
}

[MyAspect]
Task<object> Method1<T>() {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

I have tried to find the minimal set of action to reproduce this problem and here it is:

1. Create empty Windows Phone 7.1 project
2. Add Microsoft.Bcl and PostSharp NuGet packages to it
3. Create simple empty aspect (like below)
4. Add somewhere generic method that returns any type from System.Threading.Tasks.dll

Full exception text:

```
Unhandled exception (3.0.31.0, 32 bit, CLR 4.5, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.BindingException: The type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1' does not exist in the target platform.
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Binding.ReflectionBindingManager.GetReferenceAssembly(IAssemblyName assemblyName, String typeName, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Binding.ReflectionBindingManager.ResolveAssembly(Type type, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.FindType(Type reflectionType, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.FindType(Type reflectionType, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at ^XJbqCOExOmCj.^i8LBKh1N(ModuleDeclaration _0, MethodBase _1, BindingOptions _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.ModuleDeclaration.FindMethod(MethodBase reflectionMethod, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at ^XJbqCOExOmCj.^4IrPP9eT(Object _0, IMethod _1, Type[] _2, Type[] _3, BindingOptions _4)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MethodDefDeclaration.^NqB3CEvX(BindingOptions _0)
   at ^Mzw3\.bgGgRlJ.^cCM832sT[??0](Object _0, BindingOptions _1, ^d1u4kZd5aJLe _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MethodDefDeclaration.GetSystemMethod(Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MethodDefDeclaration.^xHA5o+hH(Type[] _0, Type[] _1, BindingOptions _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MetadataDeclaration.^UDRJYqgBJZ7t(Type[] _0, Type[] _1, BindingOptions _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectWeaver.AspectWeaverInstance..ctor(AspectWeaver aspectWeaver, AspectInstanceInfo aspectInstanceInfo)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectWeaver.AspectWeavers.MethodLevelAspectWeaverInstance..ctor(MethodLevelAspectWeaver aspectWeaver, AspectInstanceInfo aspectInstanceInfo)
   at ^wy1eTA/ccvw/.CreateAspectWeaverInstance(AspectInstanceInfo _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectWeaver.AspectWeaverTask.^lp9i7ZhC(InstructionWriter _0, AspectInstanceInfo _1, StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1 _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectWeaver.AspectWeaverTask.^Vyy/rF6E.^Qs9Uz9QP(IMetadataDeclaration _0, AspectInstanceInfo _1)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1.^lNgKC+Z4(IMetadataDeclaration _0, Func`3 _1)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1.^RdBVqi\.M.^8/pSq47Q(IMetadataDeclaration _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1.^d+wOzSPF(IMetadataDeclaration _0, Func`2 _1)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1.^+g+TCqVg(TypeDefDeclaration _0, Func`2 _1, Set`1 _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1.^fJqG(Func`2 _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectInfrastructure.StructuredDeclarationDictionary`1.^fJqG(Func`3 _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.AspectWeaver.AspectWeaverTask.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation)
```

Comment: I recorded this issue in our bug tracking system (#3762). I'll get back to you when I have something new. Sorry for delay. We're a bit slower than usual during the summer period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is **by design** in PostSharp 3.0.31 because `Microsoft.Bcl` would need to be supported explicitly. I added a feature request on http://postsharp.uservoice.com/forums/4949-general/suggestions/4225929-support-for-microsoft-bcl.

-gael